# How to param a "ansible -i host_filename"

Tags: ansible

How to replace "-i hosts" in ansible command?

```
ansible all -m ping -i hosts
```

by

```
ansible client -m ping
```

I desire all new project dir contains a host file and ansible read this file for host list.

Cordially,
CHCH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a "ansible.cfg" file **in project dir.**

   touch ansible.cfg
2. Insert 2 lines:

   [defaults]
   inventory = /$DIR_PROJECT_NAME/hosts
3. Create a "hosts" file **in project dir.**
4. Insert host list in file :)
5. **Enjoy!**

Answer (score 0):

You can set that in the `ansible.cfg` file.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_configuration.html